# puppet agent run backup of cron files

Tags: puppet

Looks like I was having wrong entry in root crontab and when I ran puppet agent it got overwritten.

```
Error: Could not prefetch cron provider 'crontab': Could not parse line "====" at root:10
```

Is there any way to recover those cron entries which was there before I run puppet agent?

Comment: Are you sure it was overwritten and not just appended?

Comment: Yes, Actually there were some wrong entries in crontab and due to that it deleted all the entries and written the cron details whatever configured thru puppet only.

Comment: Possibly look into puppet's file bucket... pretty sure you will need the original file's md5 sum though.